# Python client for Compute Engine returns "Required field 'resource' not specified"

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-api-client

I'm trying to create a VM using the python client. The call I'm making is

```
import googleapiclient.discovery

compute = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1')
compute.instances().insert(
    project='my-project',
    zone='us-central1-c',
    body=config).execute()
```

(config is a json string, [available here](https://pastebin.com/v5fZufri))

and the response is

```
<HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project/zones/us-central1-c/instances?alt=json
returned "Required field 'resource' not specified">
```

From [this forum post](https://forum.bubble.is/t/required-field-resource-not-specified-google-compute-engine-api/27639) and [this stackexchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37752982/post-to-google-apis-compute-engine-gives-400), it appears the problem is with the REST API headers. However headers aren't exposed the python client, as far as I know.

Is this a bug or is there something else I might be doing incorrectly?

**EDIT**

Following the error back to `googleapiclient.http.HttpRequest`, it looks like the `HttpRequest` object generated by `build()` has headers

```
{ 'accept': 'application/json',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  'content-length': '2299',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'user-agent': 'google-api-python-client/1.7.7 (gzip)' }
```

I tried adding `'resource': 'none'` to the headers and received the same response.

After looking at this for a while, I suspect the REST API is expecting a Compute Engine resource to be specified. However, searching for the word "resource" on [the official docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/) yields 546 results.

**EDIT2**

Created [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/608).

Comment: I have found a [sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/compute/api/create_instance.py) in github for creating an instance using [Google Python Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/python-guide). I would recommend you to compare the sample code with your json configuration and see if any parameter is missing. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Digil, thank you but unfortunately I started with the [corresponding python tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/python-guide) and that's what led me to this error. The code I've posted is essentially a slimmed-down version of that.

Comment: When calling compute.instances().insert(), you have looked at path parameters on top of the page, that is solely to "project" and "zone". There are other needed parameters, for instance machine type. It may be worthwhile revising the "Method: instances.insert" documentation [page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/insert) for all required parameters, and make sure you supply them all in your call.

Comment: @George According to the docs, the only required fields in the request body are `name` and `machineType`, which I've specified. Did you mean something else?

Comment: On the referenced "Method: instances.insert" page, name is required, and possibly other values. It is worthwhile checking, ad your error "Required field 'resource' not specified" seems to indicated a missing resource value.

Answer (score 0):

Use the request body(requestBody)" instead of resources.